# why Python local variable referenced before assignment shows here?

Tags: python, local-variables

```
class Solution:
    def pathSum(self, root: TreeNode, targetSum: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        ans = []
        tmp = []
        sum_node = 0
        def dfs(node):
            if not node:
                return
            sum_node += node.val
            tmp.append(node.val)
            if sum_node == targetSum and not node.left and not node.right:
                ans.append(tmp[:])
            dfs(node.left)
            dfs(node.right)
            sum_node -= tmp.pop()
        dfs(root)
        return ans
```

It's my solution of leetcode 113. Why it shows 'UnboundedLocalError: local variable 'sum_node' referenced before assignment'?

Answer (score 2):

Because `sum_node` is not a local variable to the `dfs()` function (and as such, you can't use augmented assignment such as `+=` since there's nothing to read-and-write; attempting to do `sum_node = ...` would work, but would only affect a local name).

You'll need to add a `nonlocal` statement to have the inner `dfs()` function's `sum_node` name refer to the `sum_node` name in `pathSum()`.

```
def dfs(node):
    nonlocal sum_node
    ....
```